# Struts2 Complex Conditional Validation

Tags: validation, struts2

Ok I've read loads of 'duplicate' posts on this but they are all simple examples and mine just does not fit that bill...

I'm looking to run conditional validation and want to use XML out of the box as much as possible so I'm not rewriting the basic, out of the box validation.

Situation: I have a radio box with 2 options which validates a set of addresses i.e. many form fields not just a single field dependent on which is selected

This is one example but I have others areas like this even more complicated

**What I'm looking for is ideas on how I go about this ?**

I do not want to use expressions as it involves too many fields after the initial condition. This is what all other questions answer with on SO but not viable

You can't nest validation within the XML.

I could write bespoke code in `validate()` however as I'm validating many addresses (for example) reusing code is difficult without getting the field validation map, adding errors and using `setFeildErrors(map)`. I also do not get the use of the out of the box XML validation.

I could validate the entire section and then remove errors within `validate()` but that doesn't seem correct

Interceptors are another option but I'm unsure of how you validate one address field without the other

Can someone point me in the right direction please ?

Comment: try a custom validator

Comment: Do you know about `validateZZZ()`, where ZZZ is action method, methods?

Comment: @AleksandrM no I did not... Looking at it you create a separate validation XML dependent on the action method if I understand correctly. Question is how do you submit to a different method dependent on user choice with in the form ?

Comment: Also I can't see how a if(x) <validate a> elseif (y) <validate b> can be achieved through a custom validator with validation being completed within XML... I initially thought short-circuiting would do this but my understanding of short-circuiting was wrong...

Comment: In custom validator you can inject your own logic when validating some field or all fields with a non-field validator.